Звук перестал работать после чистки Avast cleaner
Включил Avast cleaner и вдруг перестал работать звук.тел Xiaomi 9T זAndroid 12
Пишет ошибка media player error 1(-19).... Нет звука на при звонке ни при проигрывании музыки.

В телефонах на базе Андроид есть сброс до заводских настроек и полная переустановка оси. Снимите ценные данные с телефона, проверьте наличие всех паролей и вперёд. Именно чистая переустановка, а не загрузка резервной копии. С таким набором данных Вы вряд ли дождётесь чего-то вразумительного здесь.
